# How do i loop through objects in an array in ionic v3

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework

I have an array made up of objects within the object there is also another object. I have managed to get the value of supplier name using the loop below, however it's only returning value from one object. I would like to know how to get supplier name from all the objects

```
this.storage.get("products").then((data)=>{

 this.inputRowValues = data[0];
 for(let i = 0; i <= data.length; i++){
  this.user = this.inputRowValues[0]['species'].id
  this.supplier =this.inputRowValues[0]['user'].supplierName

 }
```

0: Object { id: 1559565693469, user: {…}, species: {…} } 
​
1: Object { id: 1559565830396, noofboxes: "1", price: "1", … } 
​
2: Object { id: 1559565855919, user: {…}, species: {…} } 
​

Answer (score 0):

In your code, inside the loop, you don't use the variable i to iterate over the array, so you only process the first object. Be careful also, the condition to end the loop must be `<` not `<=`. Also, to store all the users and suppliers, `this.user` and `this.supplier` must be arrays.

I propose this correction (if I understand your problem correctly) :

```
this.storage.get("products").then((data)=>{

for(let i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
  this.user.append(data[i]['species'].id)
  this.supplier.append(data[i]['user'].supplierName)

}
```